Why does lecttuce send lua script load command to all nodes (including replicas) in redis cluster?
I tried scriptLoad method of Lecttuce with Redis cluster (3 master, 2 replicas, 1 replica down)
Expected: scriptLoad method run successfully
Actual: An error occurred that informed lecttuce could not connect to one node in the cluster
It seems that Lecttuce has to send the command to all the nodes in the redis cluster. If a replica node is down, the request would fail.
As I understand, Redis has a mechanism to replicate everything from master to replica. So why does lecttuce have to send lua script load command to all nodes (including replicas) in redis cluster?

Does the explanation in https://github.com/redis/lettuce/issues/720 help understand the design decision?

Tks for your answer in https://github.com/redis/lettuce/issues/2853
